# Removing unwanted CSS from a link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, href

I need a link on our site to not inherit the CSS rules of the page - at the moment it shows with a border and underline etc which is not desirable for this particular link.

I seem to vaguely remember being able to change the href to as `<a href="javascript:;"></a>` which effectively overrides the CSS but I don't remember how to make the link go to the required page. Can you fill me in? Thanks!

Comment: What are the offending CSS rules?

Comment: The link is actually an image. All images on our site have padding and a border added. I remember only vaguely the javascript solution which overrides the CSS regardless of what rules are there (useful in case those rules are added to later on).

Comment: Why don't you add a css class to the link to reset the css styles?

Comment: And to answer your question about making the link go to the required page, you can do `href="javascript: document.location.href='http://www....';"` But you should follow @bfavaretto's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the styles being defined on the stylesheet. There are several ways to do that (examples below set color to red, but you'll actually have to set `border: 0; text-decoration: none;`).

**Inline styles**

```
<a href="#" id="thelink" style="color:#f00;">link text</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('thelink').style.color = '#f00';
```

**External CSS or `<style>` block** (if you can add a specific CSS rule for this element)

```css
#thelink { color: #f00; }
```

If the above doesn't work because of some more specific selector taking precedence:

```css
#thelink { color: #f00 !important; }
```